# InterfaceError using PyMySQL (database connection closes)

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, database, pymysql

I use PyMySQL library and Flask in my program. My view function accesses the database every time it called. After some calls it breaks and raise `InterfaceError(0, '')`. All next requests also raise InterfaceError (any db query, specifially).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   (several files of mine and Flask)
  File "/home/maxim/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/maxim/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/maxim/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 516, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/home/maxim/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 750, in _execute_command
    raise err.InterfaceError("(0, '')")
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
```

I read PyMySQL library code and saw, that this error occures if connection's `_sock` variable is None (i think it means connection is closed). But why is it happen?

I use one connection object for all view functions (i.e. it is defined outside functions). Do I do it right or I must make new connection every request? Or I need do something other to get rid of this error?

My code: https://pastebin.com/sy3xKtgB 
Full traceback: https://pastebin.com/iTU75FUi

Comment: i doubt that this is your basic problem, see http://zetcode.com/python/pymysql/  and see if your code matches this  for example result = self._query(query) doesn't look right at all

Comment: It's not my code, it's library files

Comment: pleas show us your code and which library you are using. also what exacly is your query

Comment: I have added links with code + requests and full traceback

Comment: i ran your code but mine doesn't like balance at all, pymysql doesn not make problem.i use python 3.8.5

Comment: i got this error after 10-25 request for a short time. Maybe the problem is in the Python or pymysql version?

Comment: this sounds more like a connection problem, see oif the server has reached its limits, look at the error log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by creating a new connection to db every request.

```
def get_db():
    return pymysql.connect(
        'ip',
        'user',
        'password',
        'db_name',
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )
```

I call this function every request.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from my_utils import get_db

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/get', methods=['POST'])
def get():
    conn = get_db()
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
try —— except
```

And reconnect to database only when it is necessary.

For example:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(
    'ip',
    'user',
    'password',
    'db_name',
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)
query = connection.cursor()

try:
    query.execute ( "" )
except pymysql.err.InterfaceError:
    connection.ping(reconnect=True)
    query.execute ( "" )
```